# Taking input from user via UI (shiny package used) and storing it in object in R

Tags: r, variables, shiny

I am working on a searching based web-interface tool and it requires me to connect a DB to the interface. The interface will be simply taking input from user and search it in the db and spit out the result.

Now the problem is how do I store the input from user in a variable and then pass it on later to the R file which is handling the dbconnection.

Here is the view of the files i am using for the tool, m still working on the server.R

Please help.......

**dbconn.R**

```
library(RPostgreSQL)

db.conn = function()
drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- dbConnect(drv, user="postgres", password="xyz", dbname="ICD_9_10_Mapping",host = "localhost", port = 5432)
}
test.dbconn <- db.conn()
query <- "SELECT icd_10_codes, flags FROM icd_9_10_pro WHERE icd_9_codes=$in"
query
res <- dbSendQuery(test.dbconn, statement = query)
out <- fetch(res, n = -1)
out
cat("Total ICD-10 Codes found against your search: ",nrow(out),"\n")
```

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)
require(dbconn)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Shiny Text"),

  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("dataset", "Type an ICD-9 Code here:", value= "I want to pass the variable"in" here coz in dbconn i am passing the in variable to search in db" ),

  mainPanel(
    verbatimTextOutput("summary"),

    tableOutput("view")
  )
))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the input with his id (input$dataset) in the server side.

Server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  in <- input$dataset

})
```

Now you can use the text you type in the text input as the "in" variable.
(Load dbconn.R into the server code or set the "in" variable as a global var with `in <<- ...`)

Comment: I made some improvements in the code. I have included the dbconn as a function in the server.R and after running the program successfully for the original idea. I started including the vice-verse case using a switch statement with radiobutton in UI....but following error pops up <br/> `Error in switch(code, ic9 = { : EXPR must be a length 1 vector` <br/> <br/> Here is the code I ended up making: <br/>

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21060904/r-shiny-server-r-radio-button-not-behaving-the-expected-way